# How to search for separate key and value fields in an array in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

My ElasticSearch documents contain a *nested* collection of form fields. Each field has a name and a value and the mapping is as follows:

```
form: {
  properties: {
    id:         { type: 'integer' },
    name:       { type: 'text' },
    form_data:  {
      type: 'nested',
      properties: {
        'name':  { type: 'keyword' },
        'value': { type: 'text', analyzer: 'full_text_analyzer' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to allow the user to search for multiple form fields to refine their search. They can choose which fields to search by and assign a value to each. For example

```
applicant_name = 'Joe'
pet_type = 'dog'
```

This would find all documents that contained a field named `applicant_name` which had a value fuzzy matching `Joe` as well as a field named `pet_type` and a value fuzzy matching `dog`.

The query I'm trying to do this with is as follows.:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "nested": {
          "path": "form_data",
          "query": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        { "term": { "form_data.name": "applicant_name" } },
                        { "match": { "form_data.value": "Joe" } }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        { "term": { "form_data.name": "pet_type" } },
                        { "match": { "form_data.value": "dog" } }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get 0 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a nested query per condition in your initial "must" clause:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "form_data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  { "term": { "form_data.name": "applicant_name" } },
                  { "match": { "form_data.value": "Joe" } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "form_data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  { "term": { "form_data.name": "pet_type" } },
                  { "match": { "form_data.value": "dog" } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That did it. It would be great if you could include an explanation of why this approach worked while the original one did not.

Comment: Glad it worked! Unfortunately my understanding of ES is still pretty shallow so i'm not sure why the original query did not work.